# MySQL How to print the result of this query?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have this query:

```
$sql = $link->query("SELECT m.id_rel, (SELECT SUM(visita) as total FROM icar_mas_vistas WHERE id_rel = m.id_rel), icar_categorias.nombre
FROM icar_mas_vistas AS m, icar_categorias WHERE m.id_rel = icar_categorias.id_categoria");
    if($sql->num_rows){
        while($row = $sql->fetch_object()){
            echo '<a href="?go=14&action=1&do=ver&id='.$row->id_rel.'" onClick="parent.frames[0].location.href=\'menu.php?do=14\'" class="vincAl">'.$row->total.' '.$row->nombre.'</a>';
        }
```

It's working great in the SQL console, but when printing in PHP the value of total is not showing, how can i print it?

Thanks

Comment: How should we know?! You don't show the code that is not working.

Comment: You only use an alias in the inner `SELECT` - does sth like `SELECT .., (SELECT SUM(..) FROM ..) AS total ...` work?

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same database? Are you sure there's data in the appropriate tables?

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes it's data in the tables, and its connecting to the right DB, if i execute the query in the console it works, but in php it prints everything unless the total

Comment: @kingkero yup, but its killing the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change query adding **AS total** after brackets, to:

```
SELECT m.id_rel, 
(SELECT SUM(visita) as total FROM icar_mas_vistas WHERE id_rel = m.id_rel) AS total, icar_categorias.nombre 
FROM icar_mas_vistas AS m, icar_categorias 
WHERE m.id_rel = icar_categorias.id_categoria
```

Comment: hey thanks! it worked, i don't know how i didn't saw it before, it was breaking my head since 1 hour ago